# How to use Crontab for a java file in linux

Tags: linux, cron

How can I use Crontab in Linux specifically for a Java program? I want to run a MIS Script. How can I crontab it and what should the path be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this Java application is a console based app there is nothing inherently special you need to do just because it's a Java application.

If you have a Java `.class` file, run the application like so:

```
$ java HelloWorld
```

If you have a `.jar` file, run the applicaiton like so:

```
$ java -jar myapp.jar
```

#### Cron job

To make either of the above methods a cron job simply add these to a Bash script and put that script into one of hte designated crontab directories or simply add the above command to a crontab entry.

#### Examples

1. Making a script

   Here's a script, `myjavawrapper.bash`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Do any CLASSPATH stuff here
   $ java -jar myapp.jar
   ```

   Then put `myjavawrapper.bash` in one of the cron job directories or system crontab:

   ```
   $ ls -d1l /etc/cron*
   drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov  1 23:58 /etc/cron.d
   drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 23:46 /etc/cron.daily
   -rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 29  2011 /etc/cron.deny
   drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Oct  8  2011 /etc/cron.hourly
   drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec 18  2010 /etc/cron.monthly
   ```

   -rw-r--r--  1 root root  451 Jun  2 12:10 /etc/crontab
       drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 12  2011 /etc/cron.weekly
2. Add an entry to `/etc/crontab`

   Add a line such as this to the crontab file:

   ```
   */30  *  *  *  * root  (cd /path/to/class/file; java HellowWorld)
   ```

   The above will run `java HelloWorld` every 30 minutes.

The above are just 2 methods, they aren't the only methods. This is just to give you some ideas and approaches on how to accomplish the task. There are several other ways.

Comment: I'm not sure if `30 * * * *` will run every 30 minutes. Isn't it supposed to be `*/30 * * *` there?  I think the command as it is will run at e.g  `01:30 02:30 03:30`

Comment: @val0x00ff - thanks, you'd be correct. That runs it at 30 minutes past the hour. I'll fix.